# Radio Button and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

What I have her is an if that cheeks a result that comes from a database. If that result is equal to `Sim` so radio that corresponds to `Sim` is cheeked, and then is executed a piece of code. If "No" radio check then execute another code. But when I come back to `Sim` it does not want to execute de "Sim" piece of code.

Why?
My code is:

```
<?php if ($escreve31==="Sim" ) {echo "<p>
                <label>
                    <input type='radio' required='' name='representa_selecao_regional' value='Sim' id='dasdasSim'  checked='checked' />Sim
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type='radio' required='' name='representa_selecao_regional' value='Não' id='dasdasNão' />Não
                </label>
            </p>";} else{echo "<p>
                <label>
                    <input type='radio' required='' name='representa_selecao_regional' value='Sim' id='dasdasSim'  />Sim
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type='radio' required='' name='representa_selecao_regional' value='Não' id='dasdasNão'  checked='checked' />Não
                </label>
            </p>";} ?>Se sim ,desde que anos?
<input type="text" id="desde_ano" required="false" name="desde_ano" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" maxlength="3" id="desde_ano" disabled="disabled">
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("dasdasSim").checked) {
            document.getElementById("desde_ano").removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
        } else if (document.getElementById("dasdasNão").checked) {
            document.getElementById("desde_ano").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
        }
</script>
<hr/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font size="+1">5.1 Se não, já representou anteriormente?</font>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" required="" name="representou_antes" id="representou_antesS" value="Sim" disabled="disabled">
        <label>Sim</label>
        <input type="radio" required="" name="representou_antes" id="representou_antesN" value="Não" disabled="disabled">
        <label>Não</label>
        <br>Se sim ,durante quantos anos?
        <input type="text" name="durante_anos" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" id="durante_anos" disabled="disabled">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the variable `$escreve31` set?

Comment: $receber31= "select representa_selecao_regional from caracterizacao_da_pratica_desportiva
where indentificacao like " .$idnr24. ""; 
$resultadosql31=mysql_query($receber31);
$recebe31=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultadosql31);
$escreve31= utf8_encode("{$recebe31['representa_selecao_regional']}");

Comment: @user3199227 always use english not spanish in code it's good for you and for the others :)

Comment: Well, for a start you could output the contents of that variable right after `utf8_encode` and see what it actually is. Are you sure the database result is always `Sim` (with first letter capitalized)? Or are there other spellings possible as a result? You should normalize that result to all lower case or all upper case and compare then. Another "maybe" issue is the strict equals comparison `$escreve31 === "Sim"`. It's been a while I programmed in PHP, so I don't know what exactly happens there with that string literal. It may have a different data type than the variable. Rewrite it as `==`.

Comment: @sbaaaang Its Portuguese. Sorry i did not know it.

Comment: @NobuGames The part of reciving the data ("Sim" or "Não) is working. But when I checked the oposite of the data ercived it does't execute the code. f.e If Sim is ckeked then the text field if disable but when i press the Não it doesn´t execute that part of the code

Comment: @user3199227 np man you're welcome, just to get better help english is better :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `==` because `===` operator is used to compare different types with identical values.